# How to get the successful build numbers of master branch of another job using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

i am new to groovy script. i have 2 jobs deploy_job and build_job. i want successful build numbers of master branch of build_job

I need to write a groovy script in deploy_job that gets the successful build numbers of master branch of build_job.I was not able to find the methods that i can use to get the master branch name with build numbers. The below script displays the build numbers of all the branches(master,feature,bugfix etc)

```
import hudson.model.*
def builds = []
def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("build_job")

job.builds.each {
def build = it
if (it.getResult().toString().equals("SUCCESS") ) {
    it.badgeActions.each {
             builds.add(build.displayName[1..-1])
}
   }
    }
builds.unique();
```

want to retrieve the  build numbers of master branch only. Any help would be much appreciated